# Store ImageView's in ArrayList and Stack Android

Tags: android, arraylist, stack, imageview, sharedpreferences

I am writing a card-game application.

I represent the Deck of cards using an `ArrayList<ImageView>`, and i represent the "cards stacking up on the table"(For rollback purposes) in a `Stack<ImageView>`.

How can I store the state of both the `ArrayList<ImageView>` and the `Stack<ImageView>` in order to pick up from where i left off earlier. 
I can only think of `SharedPreferences`, which only supports primitives and Sets.

Comment: Why are you using the actual ImageViews as the models? You should instead create an actual representation of a Card and then store that. Have some other piece of code convert your `Collection<Card>` into something in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your might want to consider using a SQLite database for this. Your columns would be the properties on the object you want to store. If you add on "order" property you can then use the SQL logic

```
order by `order` DESC
```

at the end of your query to get them back in the correct order.

Here's a guide:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: If it works for you, please mark the answer as correct so it will no longer appear in an unanswered state.